# I used Carousel_Slider package in my flutter app and faced an issue?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used Carousel_Slider package to build an image slider for my flutter app and I copied the parts of the code  that I needed .SO after runnig the app I faced an issue that says ...

: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List' because 'List' is not nullable.

carousel_slider.dart:59

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  framework.dart:1
  : items = null,

This is the whole DEBUG CONSOLE..

I used Carousel_Slider package to build an image slider for my flutter app and I copied the parts of the code  that I needed .SO after runnig the app I faced an issue that says ...

: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List' because 'List' is not nullable.

carousel_slider.dart:59

- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  framework.dart:1
  : items = null,

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Islam\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Islam\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

based on error logs ,
the List that you are giving in CarouselSlider Widget is null,
print your list in build to check what is the value of List that used in CarouselSlider.